# linux kernel: why kernel crash dump sometimes not generated

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, crash-dumps

I'm developing a kernel module. My env is centos 7.1 and I can find crash dump under the **/var/crash** folder.

But not every crash will generate a crash dump under the /var/crash folder, which makes me miserable to debug.

I do not know why **sometimes a crash dump is generated but sometimes not**. I do not have any related settings in my .bashrc. Could someone help with this?

Comment: have you read https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kdump/kdump.txt ?

Comment: my kdump service is on by default and my boot cmdline contains crashkernel=128M, so I expect crash dump generated everytime. So I do not know why sometimes crash report is not generated. Is it due to the preserved memory size 128M is not enough?

Comment: could be; it's not that large usually, though.

Comment: Some crash situations don't allow kernel to do **anything useful**. Such situations could occure, e,g, if something bad occures while atomic context, or scheduler data have been corrupted. The kernel is just dead, so it cannot generate crash dump.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks. I try to increase crashkernel to 512M and it still has no crash dump generated. I think I've broken some important data as you said.